# how to split a string into individual string?

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, split

I'm trying to split the string `39 -562 -18` whereby they represent XAxis, YAxis and ZAxis respectively. How do I split them into individual strings?

Comment: -1: String have method [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) which should be relatively easy to find when you are looking for ways to "split string vb.net" - you should have tried it first and than your question would be much better...

Answer (score 3):

Use `Split`. The `" "c` means a space character.

```
Dim coordinates As String = "39 -562 -18"
Dim splitCoordinates As String() = coordinates.Split(" "c)
Dim xcoordinate As String = splitCoordinates(0)
Dim ycoordinate As String = splitCoordinates(1)
Dim zcoordinate As String = splitCoordinates(2)
```

Comment: The [Split method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) takes a string delimeter not a character.  Why are you using the C character literal?  The default delimiter is a space so you actually don't need to specify it.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong Split method. I'm using [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx), which doesn't have a default.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this:

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim axis = New Axis(" 39 -562 -18")
    MessageBox.Show(axis.XAxis)
    MessageBox.Show(axis.YAxis)
    MessageBox.Show(axis.ZAxis)
End Sub
```

This is the code for the **Axis Class**

```
''' <summary>
''' Axis string Parser Class
''' </summary>
Public Class Axis
    Public XAxis
    Public YAxis
    Public ZAxis

    ''' <summary>
    ''' String containing coordinates like " 39 -562 -18"
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub New(coords As String)
        Dim axis = coords.Trim().Split(" ")

        XAxis = Convert.ToSingle(axis(0))
        YAxis = Convert.ToSingle(axis(1))
        ZAxis = Convert.ToSingle(axis(2))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Split** function

```
Dim coords = " 39 -562 -18"
Dim axis = coords.Trim().Split(" ")

Dim XAxis = Convert.ToSingle(axis(0))
Dim YAxis = Convert.ToSingle(axis(1))
Dim ZAxis = Convert.ToSingle(axis(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

WARNING MY ANSWER IS A C# VERSION NOT VB.NET:

I found this useful so I made myself a C# version too. Not sure how good my code is, I'm a newbie, but Hope this adds value to the question.

```
    char[] delimiter = { ' ' };
    string text = "39 -562 -18";

    string[] words = text.Split(delimiter);

    string xcoord = words[0], ycoord = words[1], zcoord = words[2];
    ViewBag.Message = "Xcoord: " + xcoord + " Ycoord: " + ycoord + " Zcoord: " + zcoord ;
```

What if we don't know what delimiter will be seperating the values?
Well, just add more delimiters:

```
    char[] delimiter = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t'  };
    string text = "39,-562:-18";

    string[] words = text.Split(delimiter);

    string xcoord = words[0], ycoord = words[1], zcoord = words[2];
    ViewBag.Message = "Xcoord: " + xcoord + " Ycoord: " + ycoord + " Zcoord: " + zcoord ;
```

Hope this helps anyone who runs across this thread and is like, damn, I wish I knew how to do that in C#  ... lol

So I just used ViewBag for testing purposes, but without the last viewBag line..
The **xcoord**, **ycoord** and **zcoord** should hold the respective values.

Comment: I'm actually ok with the question. Yes he could have searched for split, but I think solving the problem of splitting up something like coordinates into different variables that hold the respective values is a little more code than just splitting the string. Because you then have to do something afterwards to save those individual coords. I negated one of the downvotes, just because I'm a newbie as well and found this useful.